# Dynamically add css class with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a CSS class to an element with jQuery. This class should be an increasing number. For example, `myclass_1` then the next is `myclass_2` and so on.

It's easy to add an increasing number with a PHP `while` loop, but I don't know how can I apply PHP code inside of jQuery. Or is there another way to do this?

```
jQuery('.myclass_').popup({ 
    //code
});
```

So, how can I add an increasing number after this `.myclass_`?

Any suggestions please!

Comment: You've not really told us what you want to do with that *many* :-) classes. Probably there's away to achieve that without so *many* classes. And, do you want to select elements and add the classes following the order of the selected elements?

Comment: And what elements do you want to select, and add the classes to? Do they all have the class-name of `'myclass_'` to start with? Should this class-name be removed, or should the numbered class-name be added?

Comment: This is not a good pattern to use. Incremental identifying classes and ids become a pain to maintain. Instead use the same class name, and use DOM traversal to find related elements.

Comment: Not trying too many class. maximum 7 classes need to check with php condition. I can add this with addClass each time . But looked a better solutions. @ammarCSE has provided right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop

```
var count = 5;

for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
   jQuery('.myclass_'+i).popup({ 
       //code
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery in your project then **jQuery.each() API** will ease your effort to get it done.

**Fiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/bwdq8t5r/

One more suggestion, it would be good if you keep a generic class "myClass" on all nodes to be traversed and then append a new class with index number.

**JavaScript** [using jQuery.each()]

```
$('.myClass').each(function(index, element){
   $(element).addClass("myClass_" + index).text("Node " + index);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```